# Hosted script to click a button on another website

Tags: html, button, curl, web

Is it possible to make a script that clicks an HTML button on a website, that I do not have acces to, and then returns that website's source to the script, after the button has been clicked?

It sounds a bit confusing so I'll explain a bit further.

There is this website (a website with a bunch of articles) that has a button, that creates a link to a bunch of articles. The problem here is that the link is not direct (it cannot be accessed via the URL bar). So would it be possible to create a script (preferably PHP) that clicks the HTML button, and then returns the source code, containing information about the articles, to the script? Also that script should be runnable from my website url (hosting).

Please let me know if this isn't adequate. English is not my main language.

Comment: You cannot "click" things using cURL. Luckily the web works based on http requests which is what you are looking for. Open your browser's dev tools on the network tab and mimic the request.

Comment: Okay thank you. So, I mimicked the click action and got a link. It does however not work when I paste it into my URL bar. Also, how would this work by running a script on my website hosting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try php client for webdriver which created by facebook. 
You can find the repo here 
https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver.

This allow you to not only click HTML element with PHP, but also upload a file, expecting alert etc.

As it is written on the readme "PHP-webdriver library is PHP language binding for Selenium WebDriver, which allows you to control web browsers from PHP". So It is literally like "virtual browser" which you can control with PHP!

Well maybe you will ask "What is Selenium?".

You can find the repo here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/

Selenium is an umbrella project encapsulating a variety of tools and libraries enabling web browser automation

So it can be used as multipurpose tool. Such as web testing, virtual browser, control web browser on another computer, etc.

PHP-webdriver uses the similar concept to Java, .NET, Python and Ruby bindings from Selenium. And the new version PHP client was rewritten from scratch in 2013.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. It is the first time I write in stackoverflow.